# Modifying Objects in R so that they are Compatible for Plotting

Tags: r, dataframe, object, plot, xgboost

I found a procedure in R that is able to make a plot for observations within a dataset.

```
#source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf

library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')

bst <- xgboost(agaricus.train$data, agaricus.train$label, nrounds = 50,
eta = 0.1, max_depth = 3, subsample = .5,
method = "hist", objective = "binary:logistic", nthread = 2, verbose = 0)

xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data, model = bst, features = "odor=none")

contr <- predict(bst, agaricus.test$data, predcontrib = TRUE)

xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data, contr, model = bst, top_n = 12, n_col = 3)
```

For the above plots that are produced, I want to modify them such that only the first observation is displayed on these plots. I tried to modify the code below

```
# repeat for just one row: error

 b=(agaricus.test$data)[1,]
 b = as.matrix(b)
 contr <- predict(bst, b, predcontrib = TRUE)
xgb.plot.shap(b, contr, model = bst, top_n = 12, n_col = 3)

Error in xgb.plot.shap(b, contr, model = bst, top_n = 12) : 
  shap_contrib is not compatible with the provided data
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is this fundamentally not possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it doesn't really work that way. Here's an example - a binary variable has a score of either 0 or 1: a score of 0 = SHAP value between 0.2 and 0.5, whereas a score of 1 = SHAP value between 1.2 and 1.5 - this is what the plot is illustrating - the difference in SHAP values between 0's and 1's for that variable. Selecting the "first observation" could be an observation with a score of 0 or a score of 1, so the SHAP value that is displayed doesn't really tell you much about the variable. This is why SHAP plots require matrices of more than one observation (and why your approach isn't working).

Despite this, if you want you can pull the SHAP values for the first n observations and then plot the first observation on it's own in ggplot or base R, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')

bst <- xgboost(agaricus.train$data, agaricus.train$label, nrounds = 50,
               eta = 0.1, max_depth = 3, subsample = .5,
               method = "hist", objective = "binary:logistic",
               nthread = 2, verbose = 0)

xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data, model = bst, features = "odor=none")

contr <- predict(bst, agaricus.test$data, predcontrib = TRUE)

## Use "plot = FALSE" to return the data to "mat", instead of the rendered plot
mat <- xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data[1:2,], contr[1:2,], model = bst,
              top_n = 12, n_col = 3, plot = FALSE)

## Format the data
mat$shap_contrib %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  set_names(c("Variable", "SHAP", "second_observation")) %>% 
## Then plot however you want
  ggplot(aes(y = SHAP, x = "")) +
  geom_point(pch = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(Variable))
```

[image: example.png]

#### Updated per comments:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')

bst <- xgboost(agaricus.train$data, agaricus.train$label, nrounds = 50,
               eta = 0.1, max_depth = 3, subsample = .5,
               objective = "binary:logistic",
               nthread = 2, verbose = 0)

xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data, model = bst, features = "odor=none")

contr <- predict(bst, agaricus.test$data, predcontrib = TRUE, approxcontrib = FALSE)
pred <- predict(bst, agaricus.test$data)

## Use "plot = FALSE" to return the data to "mat", instead of the rendered plot
mat <- xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data[1:2,], contr[1:2,], model = bst,
                     top_n = 12, n_col = 3, plot = FALSE)

## Format the data
SHAP <- as.matrix(mat$shap_contrib[1,]) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  set_names(c("Variable", "SHAP"))

Score <- as.matrix(mat$data[1,]) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  set_names(c("Variable", "Score"))

Pred <- ifelse(pred[1] <= 0.5, 0, 1)

SHAP_Score <- left_join(SHAP, Score, by = "Variable")

SHAP_Score_Pred <- cbind(SHAP_Score, Pred)

ggplot(SHAP_Score_Pred, aes(y = SHAP, x = Score)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2, col = "grey75") +
  geom_point(pch = 3, cex = 3, col = "red") +
  ggtitle(label = paste("Prediction for this observation =", Pred, sep = " ")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,1)) +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(Variable))
```

[image: example2.png]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! on this plot, is it possible to add the observation ID, as well as what the xgboost model predicted for this observation (1 or 0)? Just a question: I assume the procedure you have (kindly) written, it will only work for 'xgboost', - no other models. Am I correct? Once again, thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yes - I believe it would be possible to add observation ID, prediction, etc. Have a go at figuring it out yourself, then edit your post if you need help. This example is specific to XGBoost, but you could calculate SHAP for other models and plot using the same type of approach; see e.g. dalex / shapper (http://smarterpoland.pl/index.php/2019/03/shapper-is-on-cran-its-an-r-wrapper-over-shap-explainer-for-black-box-models/)

Comment: mat <- xgb.plot.shap(agaricus.test$data[1:2,], contr[1:2,], model = bst, top_n = 12, n_col = 3, plot = FALSE) 
Why is it [1:2]? Is this selecting the first observation? Or the first two observations? If I want to only plot the first observation, do I need [1:2]?

Comment: This selects the first two observations. The reason you need more than one is that xgb.plot.shap() requires a matrix with >1 observations. The second observation is kept in the dataframe (i.e. there are three columns `set_names(c("Variable", "SHAP", "second_observation"))` but that third column called 'second_observation' is not plotted

Comment: thank you! do you know how to add the ID for the obs? I tried: id <- agaricus.test$data[1:2,]

ggplot(SHAP_Score_Pred, aes(y = SHAP, x = Score)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2, col = "grey75") +
  geom_point(pch = 3, cex = 3, col = "red") +
  ggtitle(label = paste("Prediction for this observation =", Pred, sep = " ")) +    ggtitle(label = paste("id number =", id, sep = " ")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,1)) +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(Variable))

Comment: You could try `id <- rownames(agaricus.test[1])` then you could paste it into the title with the prediction using `ggtitle(label = paste("ID =", id, "; Prediction for this observation =", Pred, sep = " "))` - it's hard to know without knowing what your actual data looks like

Comment: For selecting another observation (e.g. observation #4), i changed : agaricus.test$data[4:5,]  like this: https://shrib.com/#Brantley5B5qeRn  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - that's correct - but if you change `agaricus.test$data[4:5,]` you need to change contr too, i.e. `contr[4:5,]`, otherwise the prediction won't 'line up' with the data.

Comment: This is great! So for the 5th observation, all you need to change: agaricus.test$data[5:6,] and contr[5:6,]. Everything else (mat$data and mat$shap_contrib) stays the same?

Comment: Correct - everything else stays the same